# How to change last two digits of an integer into zero in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a 7 digit integer value and i have to replace the last two digits of that integer with zero in mysql.

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET x = (x / 100) * 100`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TRUNCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    value = TRUNCATE( value, -2 );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ec55/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set x = x - mod(x,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select TRUNCATE(( -999 / 100 ),0) * 100
    -> ;
+----------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE(( -999 / 100 ),0) * 100 |
+----------------------------------+
|                             -900 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select TRUNCATE(( 123456789 / 100 ),0) * 100
    -> ;
+---------------------------------------+
| TRUNCATE(( 123456789 / 100 ),0) * 100 |
+---------------------------------------+
|                             123456700 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `FLOOR( -999 / 100 ) * 100 = -1000`

Comment: @MT0 UPDATED ANSWER

Comment: You appear to have left caps-lock on (or just like shouting).

Comment: sorry not shouting its caps lock :)

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle:

```
select 123456789, trunc(123456789, -2) from dual;

 123456789 TRUNC(123456789,-2)
---------- -------------------
 123456789           123456700
```

And MySQL appears to have a similar function: [`truncate`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-truncate-function.php)

so `truncate(123456789, -2)` ought to work in MySQL.